# How do i get the fan speed of my GPU or CPU using OpenHardwareMonitor?

Tags: c#, winforms, openhardwaremonitor

This is the code:

```
public float? cpuView(bool pause , CpuTemperature cpuTemp , Form1 f1 , List<string> myData , float? myCpuTemp , Button b1, decimal numeric)
{
    try
    {
        if (pause == true)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("");
            foreach (var hardwareItem in myComputer.Hardware)
            {
                if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
                {
                    hardwareItem.Update();
                    foreach (IHardware subHardware in hardwareItem.SubHardware)
                    subHardware.Update();
                    foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                    {
                        cpuTemp.SetValue("sensor", sensor.Value.ToString());
                        if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Fan)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("test");
                            sensor.Hardware.Update();
                            cpuTemp.GetValue("sensor", sensor.Value.ToString());
                            if (!f1.IsDisposed)//f1.IsHandleCreated && !f1.IsDisposed)
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                                f1.Invoke(new Action(() => myData.Add("Cpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString())));
                            }
                            myCpuTemp = sensor.Value;
                            //if (sensor.Value > 60)
                            //{
                            CpulabelTemp = sensor.Value;
                            cpuSensorValues.Add(sensor.Value);
                            if (cpuSensorValues.Count == 300 && sensor.Value >= (float)numeric)                 
                            {
                                float a = ComputeStats(cpuSensorValues).Item1;
                                float b = ComputeStats(cpuSensorValues).Item2;
                                float c = ComputeStats(cpuSensorValues).Item3;
                                Logger.Write("********************************");
                                Logger.Write("CPU Minimum Temperature Is ===> " + a);
                                Logger.Write("CPU Maximum Temperature Is ===> " + b);
                                Logger.Write("CPU Average Temperature Is ===> " + c);
                                Logger.Write("********************************" + Environment.NewLine);                                           
                                cpuSensorValues = new List<float?>();
                            }
                            b1.Enabled = true;
                            //}
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        Logger.Write("There was an exception: " + err.ToString());
    }
    return myCpuTemp;
}
```

In this line:

```
if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Fan)
```

Instead Fan it was Temperature.
When it was Temperature it was working no problems.
But once i changed it to Fan to get the CPU/GPU Fan speed it dosen't get in it's jumping over this IF and keep on.

It's never get to the MessageBox.Show line.

What could be the problem ? Tried to google but nothing so far.

Comment: Maybe you don't have such a sensor, or the property has a different value. If jumps over the `if` if the expression does not evaluate to true. You could have figured this one out using a debugger.

Comment: Cody the regular original OpenHardwareMonitor program if i run it it will show me all the fans. So i have the sensor i just guess i don't know how to use it right.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the conditional

```
if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
```

The fans are not on the CPU.  You need to use the appropriate HardwareType that the fans show up on, probably `HardwareType.Mainboard`.